# CSS vs JavaScript horizontal slide / transition

Tags: javascript, css, performance

I made 2 different horizontal sliding, navigation methods ([demo](http://harmdewitonline.nl/POC%20horizontal%20slide/)).

The first is using jQuery's animate() function and the other is using jQuery to set the css *left* property to set the position and a static css *transition* property to make it slide. (only works in webkit's safari and chrome so far).

My question is, what is the best method to slide my content. The content i need to animate is pretty large, that's why i'm having concerns about the performance using these methods.

And another related question: Does content that moves outside the browsers window affect the performance a lot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your second option only works in webkit browsers I think the answer is pretty clear.

Also, I would assume that jQuerys own animation function would be the one that's the fastest.

Content outside the browser windows doesn't put a bigger strain. In fact, it should probably be faster, since the browser doesn't have to render anything.

Comment: *"Also, I would assume that jQuerys own animation function would be the one that's the fastest."* Faster than a transition built into the HTML engine (WebKit)? Not likely. Possible, but not likely.

Comment: Ah, read it too fast, didn't see he was referring to a built in method. But it's still not a viable option to rule out all other browsers, he would need to add a fallback option.

Comment: You'd think, yeah. :-) No offense to the WebKit guys, and it's going to change a **lot** in the next couple of years as Chrome gets penetration, but for now they're like 11% of the total...

Comment: I'm thinking about using the  css animation and totally drop the animation for non-webkit browsers. in my experience webkit currently has the best performance. The other browsers do not run the animation so smoothly. By only using the CSS method fast browsers will run the animation and others will nicely degrade to instant positioning.